# inotify: avoiding a loop of repeated file changes

Tags: permissions, inotify, ownership

I am using `inotify` (implemented via `pyinotify`) on my Ubuntu 18.4 system in order to monitor creates, modifies, and attribute changes in certain directories.

I use these watch flags: IN_CREATE, IN_MOVED_TO, IN_MOVED_FROM, IN_MODIFY, and IN_ATTRIB

One of the things I do when `inotify` notices one of these changes to a file is to do a `chmod` and sometimes even a `chown` on the file. For example, if the modification date of one of these watched files changes (*e.g.*, via a`touch` command), or if the size of the file changes, I will perform a `chmod` and possibly a `chown` on that file.

However, with the IN_ATTRIB watch flag, the `chmod` and `chown` flags trigger another IN_ATTRIB change, and this results in my re-issuing the command, which in turn causes the file to be noticed again and again by IN_ATTRIB, resulting in a loop of identical changes.

I want to avoid this. One way I know I could do it is to check the permissions and ownership before issuing `chmod` or `chown`, and only run either of those if a change is really needed. However, I'm wondering if there is a way in `inotify` (or `pyinotify`) to cause a change being made in the watcher program to be ignored.

I know that I can temporarily disable watching that one particular file, but then I have to re-enable watching it at some point, in case there is another need to modify the file.

Aside from checking the permissions and ownership before issuing `chmod` or `chown`, is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Given that I have gotten no responses, and given that further investigation yielded no info about how to get `inotify` to ignore changes that it makes itself to files and directories, I am now assuming that there is no way to do this, short of coding logic in my watch routines to not actually make calls to things like `chmod` and `chown` unless the attributes or ownership are actually currently different from the intended values.

This requires lots of extra logic in my code, but it also solves the problem.